# Angular sending OPTIONS requests when the Authorization header is included

Tags: angular, http, request, http-headers, preflight

I added `Authorization` in the request header (see below) on Angular (Angular 12), and the browser (Firefox v.119.0b6) started sending `OPTIONS` preflight requests which seems like they're checking whether the `authorization` header is allowed or not since it includes `Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization` in the preflight request header.

Here's how I added the `Authorization` header in the http-interceptor:

```js
req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`) })
```

My question is if this is normal (and if so, my guess is that the lowercase 'a' made the browser think like it's a custom header?), or if there's something I need to change. The request went through fine on Firefox (Chrome/Edge doesn't work since I'm sending it from localhost), but I couldn't find anyone else mentioning this behavior.

I've checked with our other product (AngularJS + ASP.NET) which also sends the `Authorization` header, but it's not sending the `OPTIONS` preflight request.

Checked on Chrome with `--disable-web-security` turned on, it doesn't have the preflight requests either.

Comment: Yes, that's normal for any non-"simple" request: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request  Pre-flights are sent by the browser for any fetch (JS, ajax call) and when custom headers are set...  when you disable web security you are turning off all CORS rules, so no pre-flight is sent.

Comment: I should add that pre-flights are only sent for cross-origin requests.  The front-end or backend framework has no bearing on this.  It's the browser that decides when a pre-flight check is sent.

Comment: Authorization header is not in thelist of 'simple' headers and it should make the cors complex. Is the other app that you are talking about really doing cors requests (origin of FE app and API are different)?

Comment: @Andrei you are totally right! The other one is making the request from the same origin and the one I'm seeing the preflight requests is from `localhost` to a remote server.